# MVVMCross binaries for Xamarin.mac

Tags: xamarin.ios, xamarin, mvvmcross, monomac

I am developing a mac application using Xamarin and MVVMCross, I downloaded MVVMCross binaries  from the following link https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross-Binaries .

I could not find Xamarin.mac specific dlls like Cirrious.MvvmCross.Mac.Views.Presenters, Cirrious.MvvmCross.Mac.Platform..etc . Where i can i find mac specific dlls?. Please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These aren't included in the MvvmCross-Binaries repository. Just check MvvmCross out and build it yourself.